# Matlab: read txt file with multiple format and skip the string and void line

Tags: matlab, readfile

I have 30 .txt files with the same format as shown below. From each file, I need to extract the corresponding value and matrix, hence, I need to skip the string line and also void line. I also know the total count number for each n-by-n matrix for each time step (this case we have 5 5x5 matrix). However, my code does not work.

Here is the content of txt file

```
 Current Time Step =            2

 Array - one

           1           2           3           4           5
           2           0           1           0           0
           3           1           0           0           0
           4           0           0           0           1
           5           0           0           1           0

 Array - two

           1           1           1           1           1
           2           0           1           0           0
           3           1           0           0           0
           4           0           0           0           1
           5           0           0           1           0

 Array - three

           1  0.000000000000000E+000  0.000000000000000E+000
           2  -2.43840000000000       0.000000000000000E+000
           3   2.43840000000000       0.000000000000000E+000
           4  0.000000000000000E+000  -2.43840000000000     
           5  0.000000000000000E+000   2.43840000000000     

 Array - four

           1  8.969565865552799E-004
           2  3.871274684514957E-004
           3  3.871274684514958E-004
           4  3.871274684514958E-004
           5  3.871274684514956E-004

 Array - five

           1   35472082.4364420     
           2   34502005.6533170     
           3   34502005.6533170     
           4   34502005.6533170     
           5   34502005.6533170     

 Time of Current Time Step =   0.537921191784371     

 Time at the End of Current Time Step =   0.559240045256864
```

Here is my code:

```
Nc = 5;
textFilename = ['TimeStep-2.txt'];
fid = fopen(textFilename);

for k = 1:1
    zero = sscanf(fid,'%f','Delimiter','\n');
end

for k = (1+4):(1+(Nc-1)+4)
    one = sscanf(fid,'%f %f %f %f %f',[5,inf]);
end

for k = (1+(Nc-1)+2*4):(1+2*(Nc-1)+2*4)
    two = sscanf(fid,'%f %f %f %f %f',[5,inf]);
end

for k = (1+2*(Nc-1)+3*4):(1+3*(Nc-1)+3*4)
    three = sscanf(fid,'%f %f %f',[3,inf]);
end

for k = (1+3*(Nc-1)+4*4):(1+4*(Nc-1)+4*4)
    four = sscanf(fid,'%f %f',[2,inf]);
end

for k = (1+4*(Nc-1)+5*4):(1+5*(Nc-1)+5*4)
    five = sscanf(fid,'%f %f',[2,inf]);
end

for k = (1+5*(Nc-1)+5*4+2):(1+5*(Nc-1)+5*4+2)
    six = sscanf(fid,'%f','Delimiter','\n');
end

for k = (1+5*(Nc-1)+5*4+2*2):(1+5*(Nc-1)+5*4+2*2)
    seven = sscanf(fid,'%f','Delimiter','\n');
end

fclose(fid);
```

Comment: Where does your code fail?

Comment: Error using sscanf "Too many input arguments"

Comment: Why are you using a data format like this?

Answer (score 1):

I used `fgetl` to read single line at a time and then `strtrim` and `strsplit` to remove white spaces and split it. Lastly I converted into doubles:

```
% open text file
fid = fopen('data.txt');
% initialize struct
s = struct([]);
% initialize loop variables
incArrayIdx = false; % increment array index
arrayIdx = 1; 
rowIdx = 1;
% read single line from file (removing '\n')
tline = fgetl(fid);
while ischar(tline) % while is not EOF
    % trim white space at the beginning of line
    tline = strtrim(tline);
    % split lines into cells by spaces(default delimiter)
    C = strsplit(tline);
    % convert each cell from string to double
    A = cellfun(@str2double,C);
    if any(isnan(A)) % nans come from non-numeric data
        rowIdx = 1; % reset row index
        if incArrayIdx % if need to increase array index
            arrayIdx = arrayIdx + 1;
            incArrayIdx = false;
        end
    else % didn't find nans - only numeric data
        % next time you find nan increase array index
        incArrayIdx = true; 
        % set new row in array
        s(arrayIdx).data(rowIdx,:) = A;
        % increase row idx
        rowIdx = rowIdx + 1;
    end
    % read next line
    tline = fgetl(fid);
end
% close file
fclose(fid);
```

and you get:

```
{s.data}' = 

  5×1 cell array

  [5×5 double]
  [5×5 double]
  [5×3 double]
  [5×2 double]
  [5×2 double]
```

By the way, it seems that your 3 last matrices are not 5x5, maybe this caused you the problems?

Comment: Your code is helpful, however, I also want to extract value from the first line and the last two lines. three are three single values.